# GET complexo em API Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Seguindo as boas práticas, qual seria a maneira mais adequada para realizar um GET complexo para recuperar os produtos de acordo com suas propriedades?

Imagine que temos os métodos para o modelo de negócio Produto.
[image: Tabela de métodos]

1. Utilizando query string no GET não entraria em conflito com o GET que retorna um produto específico?
2. Criar um end point especifico como /produtosbuscacomplexa não ficaria fora das boas práticas?

Poderiam por favor demonstrar com exemplos?

Comment: Na verdade, a query string não entraria em conflito porque ficaria algo como: `/produtos?queryString`, né?

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Comment: Entendi seu ponto de vista e concordo com ele, porém o que estou buscando é isso mesmo, não quero uma resposta concreta, por isso descrevi um cenário amplo. O que estou buscando é uma resposta que me de ideias e através delas eu consiga ir atrás da melhor solução para o meu problema. Agradeço seu feedback.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer com `query` mesmo, a sua rota só será identificada como `GET` de um produto específico se você enviar uma informação após a barra. Como não é o caso irá entrar no primeiro `GET` que trás todos os produtos. Nesta rota você deve colocar a lógica da busca de acordo com os parâmetros enviados.